# Downloaded size is more than real

Tags: c#, networking

I have written a program with C# and Microsoft API that show's amount of download you had, but it doesn't telling me the correct size that is downloaded, for example: If I download a 10 MB file, the program shows 11 MB is downloaded.
I also checked in network status window still tell me just like my program.
Why? Does other software in ISP  work same way that I have?

```
objIPInterfaceStatistics2 = objNetworkInterface[numberinterface].GetIPStatistics();
            long newBytesreceived;
            newBytesreceived = objIPInterfaceStatistics2.BytesReceived;
            if (checkdata == true)
            {
                checkdata = false;
                newBytesreceived = 0;
            }
            long newUsage = newBytesreceived - oldBytesreceived2;
            trafficusage += newUsage;
            float converttrafficusage = trafficusage / 1000000;
            oldBytesreceived2 = objIPInterfaceStatistics2.BytesReceived;
            worker.ReportProgress((int)Math.Ceiling(converttrafficusage));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Are we just meant to imagine what the code you've written does and how/if you've got something wrong? Please try to create a [mcve] of some sort, if you want help working out what you've done wrong.

Comment: You need to take into account network overheads

Comment: Are you sure they are using the same "measure"? They probably are showing you the size on MibiBytes not MegaBytes

Comment: Source code added

Answer (score 1):

I can just assume that the two values are calculated differently.
In general, 1 megabyte refers to 1.000.000 bytes whereas 1 mebibyte refers to 2^20 bytes => 1.048.576 bytes. Normally, megabyte is used as it is easier to calculate with.

To be sure, some example code from you where the downloaded packags are being calculated would be good^^